# SQL-Server - Date Conversion

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a date field stored in the format `16/08/2010 17:17`

I am attempting to store this as a datetime so that I can transform it.

Problem is I am getting an out of range error when I do.
How can I resolve this issue?

**My Queries:**

```
CAST(agreement_Date AS Datetime)
CONVERT(varchar,agreement_date,126)
```

**Error:**

> The conversion of a varchar data type
>   to a datetime data type resulted in an
>   out-of-range value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `CAST` use:

`CONVERT(datetime, agreement_Date, 103)`

The `103` specifies `dd/mm/yy` conversion, which I think is your issue.  SQL Server is looking for the month first, and that leads to an out-of-range exception.

Comment: I had misunderstood the conversion concept. Excellent! Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

Try CONVERT with a style of 103: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime,'16/08/2010 17:17',103)
```

-> 2010-08-16 17:17:00.000

@Edit: had wrong style argument

Comment: +1 correct answer but I am always looking to understand my problem rather than just have a quick fix